# Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' defined in class path resource (Gradle)

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

At this moment, I'm trying to build an app with CRUD functionalities with Java Spring Boot. It involves Spring Data JDBC and when I started a new project, I chose

・H2 Database

・JDBC API

・Spring Boot DevTools

・Spring Web Starter

・Thymeleaf

on the "New Spring Starter Project Dependencies" window.

The dependencies are handled by Gradle, not Maven. 
The Java version is 11, and the OS is Windows 10.

I wrote some source code and try to run the program, but I got an error message as the following.

```
2020-03-27 23:25:03.091  INFO 18988 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-27 23:25:03.148 ERROR 18988 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Users/marra/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.5.1.RELEASE/ScpReport/bin/main/data.sql]: INSERT INTO 'report' VALUES; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO 'report'[*] VALUES"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO 'report' VALUES [42001-200]
```

As the error message states that there is a syntax error in the SQL part, and I actually did find some syntax errors and fixed them, but I still got the same error message. So I began to suspect if this has something to do with a dependency issue.

But I have a very little experience and knowledge in dealing with dependency related errors, and it's hard for me to imagine how to identify which folder's which files' which statements are unnecessary or missing, or defined in a wrong way.

When I did some research by myself I found some Stack Overflow posts related to the error message that I got, but they were all projects that were using Maven dependencies, not Gradle dependencies that I'm using.

Assuming that this is a dependency problem, which part am I supposed to be looking at?

If you already happen to have a good "first suspect" or some kind of suggestion solution, it will be highly helpful if you tell me that in the following example formats.

```
[Example 1]: There should be a folder named 'XXX' that contains a file named 'YYY', and there should be a statement defined as 'ZZZ', but in your case the 'ZZZ' part is missing

[Example 2]: In the file 'AAA', there are statements 'BBB' and 'CCC' and these two are conflicting with each other. In this case 'CCC' is redundant and you should erase it.
```

Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'install' not found in root project 'ScpReport'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
```

Comment: You had a mistake in SQL statement, fix it and still have the same, am I understand you right? Have you tried to clear and build your project via gradle?

Comment: Yes, I fixed the SQL and still had the same. Do you mean 'clean' and build via 'project' in the tool bar? (Sorry, I'm pretty new to Spring Boot and not so familar with gradle) If that's what you mean, yes, I did that as well just a minute ago, but still I got the same error message as my original post when I tried to run the program via "Run as Spring Boot App"

Comment: Could you execute `gradlew install` or `gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` from command line?

Comment: I tried, but couldn't execute it. I pasted the error message that I got at the bottom of my original post.